# Wireless tools: Converting network essid to char

Tags: c

I need some help correcting this code because it prints out some weird stuff.

I used wireless tools and iwlib.h to scan for wireless networks and get their ESSIDs. When I use:

```
printf("Network name %s:", result->b.essid);
```

Then it works like a charm and prints the name out for me. However, I want to convert it to char so I can later send it over a buffer through the network.

*(Unless I can send the results and the "name extraction" can happen on the other side? Or is that not possible?)*

See the sample code below (not the full code) of how I attempt to do it but I get really random characters as a result.

```
wireless_scan_head head;
wireless_scan *result;
iwrange range;


while(result != NULL)
{
    char *network;
    network = result->b.essid;
    int k;
    int size = strnlen(result->b.essid);
    printf("\n Network ESSID:");
    for(k=0; k<=size; k++)
    {
        printf("%c", network[k]);
        k++;
    }
    result = result->next;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're also incrementing k twice.   Either do it in the for statement, or do it in the loop, but not both. (naggy point... preincrement (++k))

Comment: This is what the problem was, silly mistake on my side. Long hours work caused my brain to come to a halt :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: SSIDs can be unicode, can't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to formalize things...

You're incrementing k inside the for loop as well as in the for declaration.  Outputting every other character and actually reading past the bounds of network[] too. (You said you were very tired... that'll do it!)

Another thing, you're using the strnlen function, but without specifying the max length.  I **strongly** suggest always compiling with -Wall -Wextra and possibly -Wunused to show problems.  Be extra nit picky and use -Werror too, fix the warnings and errors shown, you'll write better code and build better habits.

Another another thing, if you can use the strlen (or strnlen) function to determine the length, your loop is redundant. A simple: (as you originally pointed out)

```
printf("Network ESSID: %s\n", result->b.essid);
```

Would suffice.

essid is probably defined in the struct as either *'char essid[xx];'*, or (better) *'char* essid;'*, which implies it's *already* a char string.  (a 'char string' in C is **NOT** stored the same way as a 'String string' in C++)

{Grin} If you *really* want to write it like that:

```
while (result != NULL) {
    char *network = result->b.essid;
    /* string length is unsigned */
    size_t size = strlen(network);
    /* so we need an unsigned index to compare */
    unsigned int k;
    /* initial part of output */
    printf("Network ESSID: ");
    for (k = 0; k <= size; ++k) {
        /* printf is overkill for a single char */
        putchar(network[k]));
    }
    /* terminating CR/LF/CRLF, printf overkill again */
    puts(NULL);
    result = result->next;
}
```

And the short version:

```
while (result != NULL) {
    printf("Network ESSID: %s\n", result->b.essid);
    result = result->next;
}
```

Best wishes on your code!

Answer (score 4):

It's a completely different problem to the one you think you have. What's happening is that you never initialize `result`, so this:

`network = result->b.essid;`

is just going to give you garbage, and this:

`result = result->next;`

will likely give you an infinite loop.

You should probably turn up the warning level on your compiler, and/or look into tools like splint and Valgrind.

Comment: The code I display above is not the full code. result has a value and it is result = head.result;

I already said that when I print result->b.essid directly, I get correct output

Comment: Ah, of course, I should have known you wanted help on the code you didn't post, instead of the code you did.

Comment: I didn't criticise your help. I just clarified. And I am simply telling you now that the issue I have is not related to any other part of the code.

Comment: I appreciate that, but all the same, if you knew what your issue was, you wouldn't be here asking the question. A lot of the time the issue absolutely *is* something the inquirer doesn't expect, so if you don't post working code, it's pretty difficult for anyone to help you, and it's vexing to anyone who tries if you're not posting important parts of your code. For instance, can you manually create a single `wireless_scan` struct and post a short, complete working program that demonstrates your error?

Comment: The issue was a silly increment as I commented further up in my question. Thanks for your time though, appreciated.

Comment: OK, glad you got your problem sorted out.